# Not able to create map with bool and vector

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a map with a bool and vector, but it does not seem right, I have similar constructor which is working, where I just replaced types.

Following is the error:

```
error: could not convert 'result.std::map< bool, std::vector<  unsigned int> >::emplace< std::pair< bool, std::vector< unsigned int, std::allocator< unsigned int> > > >(std::make_pair(_T1&&, _T2&&) [with _T1 = bool; _T2 = std::vector< unsigned int>; typename std::__decay_and_strip<_T2>::__type = std::vector< unsigned int>; typename std::__decay_and_strip<_Tp>::__type = bool](make_vec_pair(unsigned int, unsigned int)(nums.std::vector< unsigned int>::at((nums.std::vector< unsigned int>::size() - 1)))))' from 'std::pair< std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair< const bool, std::vector< unsigned int> > >, bool>' to 'std::map<bool, std::vector< unsigned int> >'
```

Code:

```
std::vector<unsigned int> make_vec_pair(unsigned int num1, unsigned int num2)
{
    std::vector<unsigned int> temp_vec;
    temp_vec.push_back(num1);
    temp_vec.push_back(num2);
    return temp_vec;

}

std::map<bool,std::vector<unsigned int>> make_map_of_result(std::vector<unsigned int> nums, unsigned int sum)
{
    std::map<bool,std::vector<unsigned int>> result; 
    std::vector<unsigned int> nums_pair;
    /* process */

    return result.emplace(std::make_pair(true,make_vec_pair(nums.at(i) , nums.at(i+1))));
}

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<bool, std::vector<unsigned int>> res_map;
    std::vector<unsigned int> numbers {6,1,2,5,4,3};
    std::sort(numbers.begin(),numbers.end())

    res_map = two_num_sum_array(numbers,5);
    for(auto &m:res_map)
        std::cout<<m.first;
    return 0;
}
```

Also, I am using below overloaded function to print vector, what's the problem

```
for(auto &m:res_map)
    std::cout<<m.first<<m.second; // m.second is vector is giving problem


std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &out,const std::vector<unsigned int> &vec){
        return std::out<<vec.at(0)<<vec.at(1);
}
```

update: This works

```
std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &out,const std::vector<unsigned int> &vec){
    return out<<vec.at(0)<<vec.at(1);
}
```

Comment: `return result.emplace` remove `return`. Should be `result.emplace(...); return result;`

Comment: I also question the rationale behind using a `map` with only two possible keys. That is terribly inefficient.

Comment: my main intention is to return multiple values(true/false, set of number)

Comment: @rafix07 When you answer the question, you should do it in the answer section so we can peer review you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not `return` the result of `emplace`, that should be two lines. You can also drop the `std::make_pair` and remove your `make_vec_pair` function.

```
result.emplace(true, std::vector<unsigned int>({nums.at(i), nums.at(i+1)}));
return result;
```

Comment: Thanks that "return" I overlooked , but I would like to do it in single expression , is there another way to do that?

Comment: No; why do you want that?

Comment: @sravs the only way to fill the map and return it in a single expression would be something like `return result.emplace(...), result;` but that is just silly. Use two separate expressions, keep the code simple and readable.

Comment: ok, thanks, by the way is it ok to return vectors or maps , I mean aren't  they little heavy ,just wondering what is best way, return references or values?